# assignment operator returning value type

Tags: c++

I discovered by accident that an assignment operator returning not a reference, but a copy, serves as a workaround to enable storing objects with `const` members in an STL container.

```
class Test_class
{
public:
    int const whatever;

    explicit Test_class(int w) : whatever(w) {}

    // note the missing &
    Test_class operator=(Test_class const& rhs) {
        return Test_class(rhs.whatever);
    }
};

vector<Test_class> vec;
Test_class foo(42);
vec.push_back(foo);
assert(vec[0].whatever == 42);
```

This piece of code *feels* very strange, but gcc compiles it and it seems to work correctly.

So where are the pitfalls?

**EDIT:**

After the `push_back()` `vec[0].whatever` is, in fact, 42. Added an assert for illustration.

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the answers! Just for the fun of it, this version also runs just fine ;)

```
void operator=(Test_class const&) {
    throw 42;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105798/why-must-the-copy-assignment-operator-return-a-reference-const-reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the accepted practice for operator overloading is not enforced by the standard or the compiler. It's just an expectation on the behaviour. You can check out some of it here: [Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading) or here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators .

The pitfall here is that your `operator=` is not really an assignment operator. Consider this code:

```
Test_class a(15);
Test_class b(20);
a = b;
```

Normally you would expect `a.whatever` to be 20 after executing this code, however it's still 15.

C++03 requires vector elements to be both copy-constructible and copy-assignable and the compiler is free to choose what to use. In C++11 they only have to be copy-constructible (or move-constructible) so no assignment operator is required.

Comment: thank you. can you explain why the compiler requires the assignment operator even though it is never used, and the copy constructor is - as you correctly pointed out - sufficient?

Comment: OK, so apparently C++03 requires elements to be both copy-constructible and copy-assignable (http://stackoverflow.com/a/3272731/596167) and the compiler is free to choose which one to use.

In C++11 (what I was compiling for) they only have to be copy-constructible so no assignment operator is needed.

Comment: thanks again! include that in your answer and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually assign anything here.  You could even declare that assignment operator as `const` because it does nothing.

```
Test_class a(17);
Test_class b(33);

a = b; // nothing happens.
```

The return value of operator= doesn't really matter, I for one typically declare it as `void`.  It only matters if you do things like `a = b = c;`, which is not very common.  And with your `operator=` this will compile, but again, does nothing at all.